# Json Schema: How should two objects with the same values be structured?

Tags: php, json, jsonschema, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/CodeBradley/contact-form-7-rest-api/blob/master/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-contact-form-7-controller.php

I'm working on an extension to the WordPress Rest API for Contact Form 7 but I'm not sure how to structure their mail objects in my JSON Schema. For anyone who has used the Contact Form 7 plugin, you may have noticed that they have the regular mail object (which is where you add form values, recipients, etc) and they have a mail_2 object for people who want to send a copy of the email to the end user.

Both of the objects mail and mail_2 offer the same properties as you can see in the schema below:

```
public function get_item_schema() {
    $schema = array(
        '$schema'    => 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
        'title'      => 'form',
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => array(
            'id'          => array(
                'description' => __( 'Unique identifier for the form.' ),
                'type'        => 'integer',
                'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view' ),
                'readonly'    => true,
            ),
            'title'       => array(
                'description' => __( 'Display name for the form.' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                'arg_options' => array(
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
                ),
            ),
            'name'        => array(
                'description' => __( 'An alphanumeric identifier for the object unique to its type.' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view' ),
                'arg_options' => array(
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
                ),
            ),
            'locale'      => array(
                'description' => __( 'The locale setting of the form' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                'arg_options' => array(
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
                ),
            ),
            'properties'  => array(
                'description' => __('The properties of the form'),
                'type'        => 'object',
                'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                'properties'  => array(
                    'form'  => array(
                        'description' => __('The content for the form'),
                        'type'        => 'string',
                        'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                    ),
                    'mail'  => array(
                        'type'        => 'object',
                        'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                        'properties'  => array(
                            'mail-subject' => array(
                                'description' => __('Subject of the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-sender' => array(
                                'description' => __('Sending email address of the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-recipient' => array(
                                'description' => __('Recipient email address of the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-additional-headers' => array(
                                'description' => __('Additional form headers'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-attachment' => array(
                                'description' => __('Attachments to include with form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-use-html' => array(
                                'description' => __('Send emails using HTML formatting'),
                                'type'      => 'boolean',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-exclude-blank' => array(
                                'description' => __('Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output'),
                                'type'      => 'boolean',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'mail-2'  => array(
                        'type'        => 'object',
                        'context'     => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                        'properties'  => array(
                            'mail-2-subject' => array(
                                'description' => __('Subject of the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-2-sender' => array(
                                'description' => __('Sending email address of the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-2-recipient' => array(
                                'description' => __('Recipient email address of the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-2-additional-headers' => array(
                                'description' => __('Additional form headers'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-2-attachment' => array(
                                'description' => __('Files to attach to the form'),
                                'type'      => 'string',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-2-use-html' => array(
                                'description' => __('Send emails using HTML formatting'),
                                'type'      => 'boolean',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                            'mail-2-exclude-blank' => array(
                                'description' => __('Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output'),
                                'type'      => 'boolean',
                                'context'   => array( 'embed', 'view', 'edit' ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
```

Currently I'm appending mail properties with mail- and mail-2 properties with mail-2 so that the post values don't get overridden when trying to edit either object. Is this the best way to handle this situation?

---

**Code that currently uses the schema:**

prepare_item_for_response() code:
(The returned $data['properties'] key values do not currently map to the defined schema, I'm assuming this need to be fixed? $data['properties'] houses the mail objects)

```
/**
 * The returned $data['properties'] values do not currently conform to the defined schema
 */
public function prepare_item_for_response($form, $request)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['id'] = $form->id();
    $data['name'] = $form->name();
    $data['title'] = $form->title();
    $data['locale'] = $form->locale;
    $data['properties'] = $form->get_properties(); 
    $data = $this->add_additional_fields_to_object($data, $request);
    $response = rest_ensure_response($data);
    $response = apply_filters('rest_api_prepare_wpcf7', $response, $form, $request);
    return $response;
}
```

prepare_item_for_database() code:

```
protected function prepare_item_for_database($request) {

    $id  = $request->get_param('id');
    $prepared_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_instance( $id );

    /**
     * update_item ensures the form ID exists before calling this method to prevent non-existant forms from being created accidentally.
     */
    if(empty($prepared_form)) {
        $prepared_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_template();
    }

    if ( isset( $request['post-title'] ) ) {
        $prepared_form->set_title( $request['post-title'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['locale'] ) ) {
        $locale = trim( $request['locale'] );

        if ( wpcf7_is_valid_locale( $locale ) ) {
            $prepared_form->set_locale($locale);
        }
    }

    $properties = $prepared_form->get_properties();

    if ( isset( $request['form'] ) ) {
        $properties['form'] = trim( $request['form'] );
    }

    $mail = $properties['mail'];

    if ( isset( $request['mail-subject'] ) ) {
        $mail['subject'] = trim( $request['mail-subject'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-sender'] ) ) {
        $mail['sender'] = trim( $request['mail-sender'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-body'] ) ) {
        $mail['body'] = trim( $request['mail-body'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-recipient'] ) ) {
        $mail['recipient'] = trim( $request['mail-recipient'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-additional-headers'] ) ) {
        $headers = '';
        $tempheaders = str_replace(
            "\r\n", "\n", $request['mail-additional-headers'] );
        $tempheaders = explode( "\n", $tempheaders );

        foreach ( $tempheaders as $header ) {
            $header = trim( $header );

            if ( '' !== $header ) {
                $headers .= $header . "\n";
            }
        }

        $mail['additional_headers'] = trim( $headers );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-attachments'] ) ) {
        $mail['attachments'] = trim( $request['mail-attachments'] );
    }

    $mail['use_html'] = ! empty( $request['mail-use-html'] );
    $mail['exclude_blank'] = ! empty( $request['mail-exclude-blank'] );

    $properties['mail'] = $mail;

    $mail_2 = $properties['mail_2'];

    $mail_2['active'] = ! empty( $request['mail-2-active'] );

    if ( isset( $request['mail-2-subject'] ) ) {
        $mail_2['subject'] = trim( $request['mail-2-subject'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-2-sender'] ) ) {
        $mail_2['sender'] = trim( $request['mail-2-sender'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-2-body'] ) ) {
        $mail_2['body'] = trim( $request['mail-2-body'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-2-recipient'] ) ) {
        $mail_2['recipient'] = trim( $request['mail-2-recipient'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-2-additional-headers'] ) ) {
        $headers = '';
        $tempheaders = str_replace(
            "\r\n", "\n", $request['mail-2-additional-headers'] );
        $tempheaders = explode( "\n", $tempheaders );

        foreach ( $tempheaders as $header ) {
            $header = trim( $header );

            if ( '' !== $header ) {
                $headers .= $header . "\n";
            }
        }

        $mail_2['additional_headers'] = trim( $headers );
    }

    if ( isset( $request['mail-2-attachments'] ) ) {
        $mail_2['attachments'] = trim( $request['mail-2-attachments'] );
    }

    $mail_2['use_html'] = ! empty( $request['mail-2-use-html'] );
    $mail_2['exclude_blank'] = ! empty( $request['mail-2-exclude-blank'] );

    $properties['mail_2'] = $mail_2;

    // For setting/updating confirmation/error messages
    foreach ( wpcf7_messages() as $key => $arr ) {
        $field_name = 'message-' . strtr( $key, '_', '-' );

        if ( isset( $request[$field_name] ) ) {
            $properties['messages'][$key] = trim( $request[$field_name] );
        }
    }

    if ( isset( $request['additional-settings'] ) ) {
        $properties['additional_settings'] = trim( $request['additional-settings'] );
    }

    $prepared_form->set_properties( $properties );

    //Preceded original with rest_api_
    do_action( 'rest_api_wpcf7_save_contact_form', $prepared_form );

    if ( wpcf7_validate_configuration() ) {
        $config_validator = new WPCF7_ConfigValidator( $prepared_form );
        $config_validator->validate();
    }

    return $prepared_form;

}
```